# Comparing different versions of same network

Tags: graph, networkx, reinforcement-learning, markov-chains

When comparing many directed networks with non deterministic transitions, each version with different definitions of states. How do I choose the best representation?

Example:

Version one I have 100 nodes.

Version two, I changed the definition of state a bit, and now I ended up with 500 nodes.

How do I know which representation is better? Why one better describe my system?

More context: the issue is that I am discretizing a few dimensions in smaller discrete buckets. And I need to get the smaller amount of buckets as possible without loosing generalization

I tried a few numbers of buckets for state. But it is hard to compare which one is better